# SharePoint 2013 - Being Removed Randomly and/or Automatically from the Admin Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I've been experiencing one particular error with SharePoint 2013.  Each time I attempt to publish a workflow from SharePoint Designer 2013 onto our site, I am removed from the Admin Permission Group.  Additionally, I am automatically removed from the Admin Group randomly, usually occurring on a weekly basis after conducting simple tasks like creating a new list/library or even just signing in.

Troubleshooting Steps:

1 - To test for errors, I've enabled the Audit Log Feature, specifically the Editing Users and Permissions Audit Log under Site Collection Administration, in hopes to track when and why I'm being removed from the admin group. However, this feature will only tracks when permissions within a group are changed not when a user is added or removed from the group. So, No Dice.

2 - We've created an owner's group which solely maintains the rights of adding and removing users from the Admin group in order to see if other users within the admin group are accidently removing other users.  This method also did not work because I am still being removed.

Furthermore, I'm beginning to believe this error is only affecting my account because no other user is experiencing similar problems.  So, is there any way to get to the bottom of this issue?  Or, would creating a new account resolve this issue?

Please Help.  Thanks in Advanced :)